# How do modern displays output data to pixels?

Tags: voltage, analog, display, data-storage

Do new displays still write pixels one at a time? I thought this was the case until I saw a video showing slo-mo footage of a display, in which it was clear that all of the pixels are on at the same time. If data is updated one pixel at a time, how are the voltage signals saved in order to maintain the correct color in each pixel? My initial thought was that the color data is stored in binary for each pixel, and digital-to-analog converters are used to convert the data into analog voltage to regulate the colors. However, this seems like a very costly method considering the massive number of pixels in modern displays.

Answer (score 1):

> Do new displays still write pixels one at a time?

If we talk about a video interface to a display, then yes, pixels are still "drawn" one at a time on the screen.

If we talk about the CPU drawing pixels there are various methods. The CPU can write 4 bytes (32 bit processor) or 8 bytes (64 bit processor ) at a time into memory.

But most display memories are not written by the CPU whilst the contents is displayed. 
Instead the memory is updated and then as a whole passed to the video controller. This is often done during the vertical blanking period. This method is preferred as it give a more 'steady' image. (Also see "bit blitter").

> I saw a video showing slo-mo footage of a display, in which it was clear that all of the pixels are on at the same time.

Just because you update/change one pixel (write it) at a time, that does not mean it will be off when it is not written.  Think of a large amount (~2 million) of three-colours<sup>*</sup> LEDs. You *change* the colour of them one at a time, but in between they still keep giving out light of the last value written. (We are no longer using an electron beam to write one spot on the screen)

<sup>*</sup><sub>In reality there is grid of 3 LEDS. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_display)</sub>

> However, this seems like a very costly method considering the massive number of pixels in modern displays

"costly" is a relative term, but yes you need some memory to store a screen image. 1920x1080 is a common format as is 24 bit colours these days so you need 1920x1080x3=6.2Mbytes. Taking into account what I wrote above, you need twice that memory for a steady picture.

Most CPU's have 4G of memory so if we set aside a part of the for the video you use ~0.3% for your display. But if you have a graphics card then it will have it's own video memory.